# accessing an array

Tags: c++

i am declaring a global array,and then assigning the values inside a if statement. But when i am using the array in another if statement the array has different values other than i assigned previously.
For example:

```
int arr[5];
xyz(bool p,bool q)
{
    if(p)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
        {
            arr[i]=rand()%100;
        }
    }

    if(q)
    {
        for(i=0;i<5;i++)
        printf("%d",arr[i]);
    }
}
```

can anyone help??

Comment: for starters, do `for( int i = 0; i < 5; ++i )` - array indices are zero-based.

Comment: `print arr[i];` is not legal C++; neither is `for(i=1 to 5)`. What's the actual code you're running?

Comment: has this got anything to do with qt?

Comment: I do get the proper output, what is inserted in the array is displayed, using VS2005. And is your code pseudo code ?

Comment: Please post the *exact* code you have trouble with.

Comment: I changed my pseudo code into source code,so folks can you now help me?? I know the syntax,i was asking about concept.

Comment: How do you know the values are different than the one you assigned: you never print the initial values, and since they are pseudo-random you would have a hard time knowing what they are (well, except if you know the seed and RNG algorithm you are using...).

Comment: @neha:  Since the code is not working as you expect, there's something you don't know, and it might well be syntactical.  Code that doesn't work as expected is typically wrong in specific, not general or conceptual, ways.  Further, if you're translating into pseudo-code, you're likely translating it as you want it to work rather than as it does work.  Please provide actual code, what you expected to have happen, what does happen, and how you know it.

Comment: You are still not showing how you call this function, and what you are expecting. As it is, that code still wouldn't compile in C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if `p != q` then any changes you make to `arr` in the first conditional will not be printed when you enter the second conditional.  If `arr` was never initialized, it will almost certaninly not have the values you expect.

**Edit:** Based on your comment below, Try using a `std::vector<int>` instead of a C style integer array, as in:

```
#include <vector>
std::vector<int> arr(5);  // was int arr[5]
```

Also a couple suggestions:

- Where practical (which is almost, but not quite always) you should be using the standard containers in C++.  They tend to be better behaved than C style arrays.
- Use of global variable can sometimes lead to more problems than they solve.  Recommend you make `arr` a local variable and pass it as a parameter where needed.  This helps people looking at your code know what it needs and what it accesses without having to actually dig through the code to see it all.  It's possible (perhaps even likely) that something else is changing `arr` without you knowing it.  If you always pass arguments and refrain from using globals, this will help you discover where it's being changed.

So, combining these I would recommend doing something like:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

xyz(std::vector<int>& arr, bool p, bool q)
{
    std::vector<int>::iterator ai;
    if(p)
    {
        for(ai = arr.begin(); ai != arr.end(); ++ai)
        {
            *ai = rand() % 100;
        }
    }

    if(q) 
    {
        for(ai = arr.begin(); ai != arr.end(); ++ai)
        {
            std::cout << *ai << std::endl;
        }
    }                    
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> arr(5);
    xyz(arr, true, false);
    xyz(arr, false, true);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I am calling function two times,in first p is true,q is false and second q is true and p is false. If in this case this is not possible then what is the way to access the array?

Comment: @neha:  Then please post some sample code showing how the function is called.  Also, show what output you expected and what output you got.  It's five integers in each case; that shouldn't be too hard.

Comment: @neha: I updated my answer in response to your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Try adjusting your first code block to something more like this:

```
if (p) {
    int temp;
    for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
        temp = rand() % 100;
        printf("%i: %d\n", i, temp);
        arr[i] = temp;
    }
}
```

Now, you will get a listing of the random values before they are written into the array.  Compare this list to what you get when you read them from the array later.

**Update:**  I ran [the above modification to your code](http://codepad.org/Zmtacxq5) on Codepad, and I am seeing the exact same values both times.

Answer (score 0):

I don't even see why you're adding those 'bool' variables since you're not creating to never run it!
So just use this code [ which is the same as beta's version];

```
int temp;

for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
    temp = rand() % 100;
    cout << i << temp << endl; 
    arr[i] = temp;
}
```